# Build or Linker order in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2022

This is a question about Microsoft Visual Studio 2022
I have multiple files `A.h` and `A.cpp`, `B.h` and `B.cpp`, and finally, `C.h` and `C.cpp`.
`A.h`

```cpp
class A
{
private:
    A();

    static A* Instance;
}
```

`A.cpp`

```cpp
A::A()
{
    Some code
}

A* A::Instance{ A() };
```

`B.h`

```cpp
class B
{
private:
    B();

    static B* Instance;
}
```

`B.cpp`

```cpp
B::B()
{
    Some different code
}

B* B::Instance{ B() };
```

`C.h`

```cpp
class C
{
private:
    C();

    static C* Instance;
}
```

`C.cpp`

```cpp
C::C()
{
    Some different code that depends on A::A() or B::B() already being ran.
}

C* C::Instance{ C() };
```

###### With this;

I must ensure that `C.cpp` is built, or linked after `A.cpp` or `B.cpp`. Using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 IDE is there anyway I can do this? In my current project, `C::C()` is ran before `A::A()`, the theoretical combined code prior to the entrypoint function would be as such:

```cpp
C* C::Instance{ C() };
A* A::Instance{ A() };
B* B::Instance{ B() };

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

How can I ensure that `C::C()` is run after `A::A()`

Thank you.

Comment: While the initialization order in any one [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149) is guaranteed, there are no guarantees about what translation unit will be initialized first. See [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) for what few details we can give about the problem. Usually the best advice is just don't do that. Either define the `static` members in a single file to guarantee the ordering, go with Chuck's answer and use singletons, or do something completely different that doesn't involve `static` members.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/how-do-you-implement-the-singleton-design-pattern/) so you don't rely on compiler-specific implementation details. If C:C requires A::A or B::B then make A and B singletons, and have C reference them through the singleton.

Specifically, have the class C implicitly create the instance it needs. Do not assume it always exists.

Also, the pattern you are using is "almost" a singleton. Something more like:

```
class A
{
public:
    static A* Get();

private:
    A();

    static A* Instance;
}

A* A::Instance = nullptr;

A* A::Get()
{
    static A myInstance();
    if (!Instance)
    {
        // most times this is heap allocated, but you can also have
        // a hidden variable instead if you insist on no
        // runtime allocations.
        Instance = &myInstance;
    }

    return Instance;
}
```

Then in your C class ctor:

```
C::C()
{
    A* ptr = A::Get();
}
```

> The basic answer is that you can guarantee the order of construction of global variables in a single translation unit (i.e. cpp file) like you did in the original code, but it's not defined for the general case between translation units. It's also really easy to change the code in future without realizing you impacted the construction order, so it's not robust to rely on it in the first place.

Comment: Side note: With singletons the destruction order will be the reverse of the order in which they were first invoked somewhere after `main` exits. Don't use them after `main` and you're safe. If you have to use them after `main`... You just moved the problem from start up to exit.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a singleton. They are just glorified global variables and cause all the same problems that global variables cause; hard to maintain code, tight coupling, naming collisions, hard to debug code, problems with order of destruction, no encapsulation, etc etc. Friends don't let friends use singletons (or globals).

Comment: Answers should be self contained rather than relying on external links, especially when the external link is to a geekforgeeks Java page. The OP is already using singletons so this doesn't even answer the question

Comment: @JesperJuhl In this case, they are using singletons "wrong" as global variables. Actually following the singleton pattern would at least work.

Comment: [Here's a link to a more appropriate modern C++ singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4581301) rather than the Java-heavy link used in this answer. It is also the first and best answer to one of the duplicates listed above. You could bypass the problem I discuss in the comments above by dynamically allocating and never `delete`ing the instance, but that could be trading for yet another problem if the instance's destructor MUST be run for correct behaviour.